# Body of delete request is empty in my rest api endpoint

Tags: rest, go, http-delete

I seem to get empty body content of a Go http.Request if the method is DELETE.  But if I change the method to POST, then the body content gives me the content I expect.

The relevant code from my golang looks like this:

```
import(
  "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
func Delete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  r.ParseForm()
  qs := r.Form
  log.Println(qs)
}


func main() {
  router := mux.NewRouter()

  router.HandleFunc("/profile", Delete).Methods("POST")
  router.HandleFunc("/profile", Delete).Methods("DELETE")

}
```

Now when I run this JavaScript code form my browser:

```
fetch(sendurl,{
  method:"POST",
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body:"data="+project.encodeFormURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"ids":[1032,1033]}))
})
.then(response=>{
  if(response.ok)
    return response.json();
})
.then(result=>{
  console.log(result);
})
```

I see a nice array of numbers in my `qs[ids]` in my Golang code.  But if I change my `method:"POST"` to `method:"DELETE"` in the JavaScript, then `qs` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

This JavaScript with the DELETE method can populate the Go `qs` variable the way one would normally expect:

```
fetch(sendurl+"?data="+project.encodeFormURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"ids":[1032,1033]})),{
  method:"DELETE",
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
.then(response=>{
  if(response.ok)
    return response.json();
})
.then(result=>{
  console.log(result);
})
```

So it seems Go will ignore JavaScript `body` argument when `DELETE` method is used, but it will respect the query string content in the API endpoint url? Why is it like that?

Comment: Can you confirm that the client/browser is sending the body? Do you have something in front of the go app, like a proxy?

Comment: In the network tab of my FireFox, I can see the body or params is being sent as `data {"ids":[6026,6024]}`.  I didn't put anything in front of my golang app.   All the POST and PUT statements have no trouble parsing the body.

Comment: This is actually hinted to by the documentation on the `Form` and `PostForm` fields ( https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3409ce39bfd7584523b7a8c150a310cea92d879d/src/net/http/request.go#L248-L253) Maybe try using the json as is, not as form-urlencoded, set the correct header for it in js, and parse the request's Body field using `encoding/json`?

Comment: And the documentation on the actual [`ParseForm`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3409ce39bfd7584523b7a8c150a310cea92d879d/src/net/http/request.go#L1239) method says *"For POST, PUT, and PATCH requests, it also parses the request body as a form and puts the results into both r.PostForm and r.Form. Request body parameters take precedence over URL query string values in r.Form."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

The query string is part of the target-uri of the request; in other words, the query string is part of the *identifier*, not an incidental modifier of it.  But the message-body of the request is *not* part of the identifier.

So your local framework, or any of the other general purpose components forwarding your request, are not required to provide support for the message-body.

Think "undefined behavior" in C.